# Is there an easy way to force a file to be cached in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

My university's wireless login page is slow because it has a blocking js file that sometimes errors out. Typically you have to wait two timeout periods because they separate the username entry and password entry.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to force chrome to cache an empty file.
I think I can do it by temporarily redirecting that domain to my local machine, requesting the same file and sending caching headers.
I really want to know if it can be done via javascript ... possibly a bookmarklet. It'd be nice to be able to distribute this to other students.

For the record, I did inform them of the problem and that they could simply push the file down but got a canned response that they had no solution.

Comment: You can write a Chrome extension that cache the file for you...

Comment: you can use [webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) to redirect requests to a Chrome extension page... or maybe just remove the script tag from the login page altogether?

Comment: Interesting ideas, I haven't looked into chrome extensions that much, thanks!